# Can I make DDoS attack with view functions?

Tags: solidity, view

As I understand the view functions does not require gas. So isn't it possible to spam the network and to overload the nodes with spamming view functions to all the nodes ?

Comment: You can’t spam the network , u can spam one node that because calling a view functions is not sending a transaction and is not propagated to other nodes

Comment: if I can spam 1 node so I can spam all the nodes. Isnt this risk to the eth nodes ?

Comment: I'm not sure :) not an expert in Ethereum clients but not all nodes are public , not all public nodes support such requests :)

Answer (score 2):

When using view functions, you load only the node you are accessing. Moreover, it can even be off-line. Other nodes of the network are not affected. The only exception is when the attacked node is generating in a private network with a PoA consensus - then it is possible to slow down the generation of new blocks in the network.